# Array não retorna valor usando uma função de método estático

Tags: php, array, formatação, console

Nesta função estática todas as variáveis retorna as respectivas valores, exceto `$funcionario` que é um array.

Onde estou errando?

```
class Dtb{

    public static $funcionarios =['M','G','N','I'] ;
    public static $atividades='Sistemas';
    public static $temp=12;

}


echo Dtb::$funcionarios;
echo Dtb::$atividades;
echo Dtb::$temp;
```

Comment: Agora você pode votar positivo em todas postagens do site, inclusive aqui, exceto a sua, claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para imprimir um *array* é necessário formatá-lo, uma das formas é o [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
class Dtb {
    public static $funcionarios = ['M','G','N','I'] ;
    public static $atividades = 'Sistemas';
    public static $temp = 12;
}
echo print_r(Dtb::$funcionarios);
echo Dtb::$atividades;
echo Dtb::$temp;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oyFNGw). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/lbmvhlzp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/Print.php).

Comment: Esqueci da existência do print_r... VLW!!